# Next.js Azure CI Pipeline: API Routes Returning 500 Error, but Working Fine Locally

Tags: next.js, middleware

I have a Next.js application with API routes that are working fine when I run the app locally. However, when I deploy the app to Azure CI Pipeline, all of my API routes start throwing 500 errors. I've been troubleshooting this issue for a while now. I have been able to pinpoint the exact cause but couldn't solve it.

The issue was identified after I realized that the API does respond well when the middleware is configured without a matcher in the middleware's config object. But it throws 500 (internal server error ) with every API request when the middleware is configured with a matcher config object.

My code of middleware.

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { jwtVerify } from 'jose'

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/api/(.*)'],
}

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    console.log('In middleware...')
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers)
    const reqUrl = req.nextUrl.pathname
    if (reqUrl === '/api/hello') {
        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({
                error: {
                    message: `Working fine On line 16...${process.env.JWT_SECRET},${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
                },
            }),
            { status: 401 }
        )
    }
    if (reqUrl.startsWith('/api/user') && reqUrl !== '/api/user/getall') {
        // TODO: Implement any middleware logic related to register
        return NextResponse.next()
    } else if (reqUrl === '/api/user/login') {
        // TODO: Implement any middleware logic related to login
        return NextResponse.next()
    } else {
        const token = requestHeaders.get('Authorization')?.split(' ')[1] || ''
        if (!token) {
            return unauthorizedResponse('No Token in header.')
        }

        try {
            const { payload } = await jwtVerify(
                token,
                new TextEncoder().encode(
                    process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'MySecretKeyWhichIsVerySecret'
                )
            )
            requestHeaders.set(
                'x-user-from-middleware',
                JSON.stringify(payload)
            )
        } catch (error) {
            if (isTokenExpiredError(error)) {
                return unauthorizedResponse('JWT token has expired.')
            }

            console.error('Error decoding JWT:', error)
            return serverErrorResponse('Error decoding JWT')
        }

        // Successfully authenticated
        const response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
                headers: requestHeaders,
            },
        })
        return response
    }
}

function unauthorizedResponse(message: string): NextResponse {
    return new NextResponse(
        JSON.stringify({
            error: { message: 'Unauthorized' },
        }),
        { status: 401 }
    )
}

function serverErrorResponse(message: string): NextResponse {
    return new NextResponse(
        JSON.stringify({
            error: { message },
        }),
        { status: 500 }
    )
}

function isTokenExpiredError(error: any): boolean {
    // Check the error message to determine if it's an expired token error
    if (error instanceof Error) {
        return error.message.includes('expired')
    }
    return false
}
```

```
--------src
      |
      ----middleware
      |
      ----pages
               |
               ----api
```